# Sequence can converge linearly with one norm but not another, and superlinear convergence does not depend on norm

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, optimization

Show that a sequence can converge linearly with one norm but not another. Show that superlinear convergence is independent of the norm.

I must find a sequence of elements $x^k$ such that

$$||x^{k+1}-a||_1\le r||x^k-a||_1$$

and $\lim x^k=a$

for $k>k_0$ for some norm $||.||_1$ but not for $||.||_2$

I tried thinking in $\mathbb{R}$ but this didn't work because all norms are equal there. I think that using the euclidean and taxi norm it may work.

Maybe something like $(\cos \frac{x}{k},\cos \frac{x}{k})\to (1,1)$. In the euclidean norm, we get $||x^{k+1}-a||=\sqrt{(\cos \frac{x}{k}-1)^2+(\cos \frac{x}{k}-1)^2}$ for the enclidean norm, but I don't think it works linearly.

I also have to prove $$\lim_{k\to\infty} \frac{e_{k+1}}{e_k}=0$$

where $e_k = ||x^k-a||$ and $\lim_{k\to\infty} x^k = a$, which is the definition of superlinear convergence.

Why this shouldn't depend on the norm?

Comment: If $\{x[k]\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is a sequence of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ that converges linearly to 0 in _any_ $p$-norm (here assuming $p\geq 1$), then it converges linearly in _every_ $p$-norm (and also in the $\infty$-norm). That is because $$||x[k]||_{\infty} \leq ||x[k]||_p \leq n^{1/p}||x[k]||_{\infty} \quad , \forall k \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$

Comment: @Michael doesn't this inequalty says that if it converges in the norm of $\infty$ then it converges in every $p$ norm? It seems a bit different from what you said

Comment: Yes.  And the first inequality says that if it converges in _any_ $p$ norm then it converges in the norm of $\infty$. The second inequality says that if it converges in the norm of $\infty$ then it converges in _every_ $p$ norm (for $p\geq 1$), since $n^{1/p}$ is just a constant factor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Consider $x^k = 0.5^k e \in \mathbb{R}^n$ with $e$ the vector of all ones.
2. Try to prove it using $||x||_2 \leq ||x||_1 \leq \sqrt{n} ||x||_2$ (or [this generalized form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Relations_between_p-norms)).

Comment: Ok, so $\lim x^k = 0$. For the euclidean norm, $||0.5^{k+1}||\le ||0.5^k||$ because $\sqrt{0.5^{{k+1}^2} + \cdots + 0.5^{{k+1}^2}}\le \sqrt{0.5^{{k}^2} + \cdots + 0.5^{{k}^2}}$ because $\sqrt{x}$ is monotone increasing. But for the taxicab norm I still think it's valid. $|0.5^{{k+1}}| + \cdots + |0.5^{{k+1}}|\le |0.5^{{k}}| + \cdots + |0.5^{{k}}|$

Comment: Doesn't $2$ just prove that if it converges in the norm $2$, then it converges in the norm $1$? I don't see a reason why it should converge in all norms

Comment: Even for the norm of the max it is still valid

Comment: @Paprika I just went over your old questions. You never give anyone credit for their answers.

Comment: I always give after the exams, you can see at my second page. It's in 2 days so I'll accept everything then. I always do like this because I always think I understood something and when studying I forget a detail then I go and ask